# Transit time allowed for checking out

Tags: transit, ams

I just want to know if I have a transit time of about 12 hours in Amsterdam airport, am I allowed to check out and be back by check-in time?

Comment: What is your nationality? What do you mean by "check out and back"? What does Detroit have to do with anything?

Comment: @Glorfindel Please don't edit on-hold posts unless your edit addresses the reason the post was closed. This is actually harmful. The first time an on-hold post is edited, it is automatically nominated for reopening. Because all you did was fix the grammar, the reopen vote will fail. The problem is that only happens the first time the post is edited. If the asker now comes back and edits the necessary information into their question, it will not automatically be nominated -- somebody will have to notice the edit and then manually start the reopen process. But that is much less likely to happen:

Comment: there's a good chance that nobody will notice any edit and that the question will never get reopened, now.

Comment: I [know of that pitfall](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303477/295232), but this edit happened *while* the post was being closed. I thought I was in time ...

Comment: I'm guessing by his old tags (USA) that OP is American, and asking if they can leave the airport during the layover, and then come back. If so, yes. You might need an additional Visa if you do not already have one.